# mongoengine embeded document in a DynamicField

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I try to embed a document into a dynamic field. But when I try to access it later, it's not a document object anymore, it's just a dict.

Here is the example code i've just made up:

```
#defining the documents
class Embed(EmbeddedDocument):
     field_1    = StringField(db_field='f')

 class Doc(Document):
     myid = IntField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
     embed_me = DynamicField(db_field='e')
     field_x    = StringField(db_field='x')
```

Then i create a new document and save it:

```
connect('test')

# the embedded part
embed = Embed(field_1='this is a test')

# the document with the embedded document
doc = Doc(pk=2)
doc.embed_me = embed
doc.save()
```

So far everything is ok. This is what I get in the db:

```
 # > db.doc.find()
 # { "_id" : 1, "e" : { "f" : "this is a test", "_cls" : "Embed" } }
```

But now, if I request the document and try to access a value from the embedded document i get an exception:

```
doc, c = Doc.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
```

just for reference: access in the main doc works

```
print doc.field_x
> None
```

also reference: the dict looks okay, except that the names from the embedded doc are not translated

```
print doc.__dict__
> {'_created': False, '_data': {'myid': 1, 'embed_me': {u'_cls': u'Embed', u'f': u'this is a test'}, 'field_x': None}, '_changed_fields': [], '_initialised': True}
```

and now, while try to access the embedded doc, the exception rises

```
print doc.embed_me.field_1
>  File "embed_err.py", line 31, in <module>
print doc.embed_me.field_1
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'field_1
```

what type is it?

```
 type(doc.embed_me)
 > <type 'dict'>
```

It looks like the embedded document is not translated in an object. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I misunderstand the concept. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.8.3 you will have to manually reconstruct it, which is a bug - so I opened [#449](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/449) and fixed in master.  0.8.4 is due later this week.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so this is a bug and i'll wait for the next release.

Comment: just got the new version, works now as expected. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [docs](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):

> class mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument(*args, **kwargs)
>
> A Document that
>   isn’t stored in its own collection. EmbeddedDocuments should be used
>   as fields on Documents through the EmbeddedDocumentField field type.

You should define an `EmbeddedDocumentField` instead of `DynamicField` on `Doc` document:

```
class Doc(Document):
    myid = IntField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    embed_me = EmbeddedDocumentField(Post, db_field='e')
    field_x = StringField(db_field='x')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm aware of the EmbeddedDocumentField type. But I want to use the field for different types so I chose DynamicField, since this should be able to store everything.

Comment: Got it, but could you temporary switch to `EmbeddedDocumentField` and check if it throws the same error or not? It shouldn' but please check.